# Why in C++ I can't declare a dynamic array of objects with parmatetrized constructors?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, dynamic

I try to make simple program that will display students names from array of objects called "Student", I know that it can be easily done using vectors but I would like to do that using dynamic array. My code:

```
class Student {
public:
  string name;
  Student(string name){
    this->name = name;
  }
};

void DisplayStudentsNames(Student array[],int length) {
  for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    cout << array[i].name << endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Student ** array = new Student *[3];
  array[0] = new Student("Michael");
  array[1] = new Student("Tom");
  array[2] = new Student("Timmy");
  DisplayStudentsNames(*array,3);
  return 0;
}
```

I am not sure why it does not work, it does compile but program just "stops responding" after displaying first student name. I wonder what is the issue, I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303820/creation-of-dynamic-array-of-dynamic-objects-in-c/20304088) that if Class does not have any zero argument constructor you cannot create an array of dynamic objects dynamically, I wonder why is that? I'm just assigining new objects to pointers (in C# that's the normal way creating a class).

Comment: `*array` is the same as `array[0]`, which is a single `Student *`.  Passing that to `DisplayStudentsNames` passes a single pointer.  Accessing `array[i]` for `i` not equal to zero is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Re: "I would like to do that using dynamic array" -- why do you want to do it the hard way?

Comment: Alright I have found my issue now, thank you so much. All I had to do was to change: ```void DisplayStudentsNames(Student array[],int length)``` to ```void DisplayStudentsNames(Student * array[],int length)``` and ```*array``` to simple ```array```, now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here

```cpp
DisplayStudentsNames(*array,3);
```

What you are actually passing to `DisplayStudentNames()` here is the first element is the array `array`. The issue is that `array[0]` is not an array, it is a pointer to a single object. Therefore when you try and iterate it you get undefined behaviour, an exception would be the best case scienorio here (as you saw with your infinite loop).

You can fix this by changing

```cpp
DisplayStudentsNames(*array,3);
```

to

```
DisplayStudentsNames(array,3);
```

and `DisplayStudentsNames` to take `Student**`

Also this wont work:

```cpp
cout << array[i].name << endl;
```

Each element in `array` is a pointer to a `Student` object and in C++ accessing an object through a pointer requires using the `->` operator (so `array[i]->name` instead).

Side note:

```cpp
Student(string name){
    this->name = name;
  }
```

This is bad C++, use initaliser lists for setting members on creation instead, as it allows compiler optimisations and is easier to read

Comment: Changing ```DisplayStudentsNames(*array,3);``` to ```DisplayStudentsNames(array,3);``` does not work because complier does not allow me to do it. Changing "```DisplayStudentsNames``` to take ```*array[]``` and then pass ```array```" does work and program runs perfectly fine, of course I also had to change all ```.``` to ```->``` in DisplayStudentsNames. I wonder what is wrong with using ```*array[]```, I don't see any other soluton..

Comment: Apologies, wasnt thinking straight. Yes sorry `DisplayStudentNames()` needs to take `Student**` for this to work, `*array[]` is just messy thats the problem

Comment: Yes you are right it does work both ways (```*array[]``` and ```Student **```) ```Student **``` is cleaner, I wonder why people said its impossible to make dynamic array with parametrized constructors tho. It works perfectly :P